# Series Index Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very simple question. I have this series

```
[in]: item_series
[out]: item_nbr
       9           27396
       28           4893
       40            254
       47           2409
```

Now I have a for loop

```
for j in item_series:
    print j
```

Right now this prints: 27396, 4893, 254, 2409. How can I get it to print the item number? In this example: 9, 28, 40, 47.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the index of a pandas `Series` using `item_series.index`

So for your example

```
for j in item_series.index:
    print j
```